# How to make a video loop in Xcode swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, video, background

I am trying to get a video background in my app and I have written the following code. It runs one time and then stops. How do I make the video repeat forever? Thanks in advance.

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoLayer: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playBackgroundVideo()
}
func playBackgroundVideo(){
   guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "City", ofType: "MOV") else {
       return
   }
   let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
   let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
   playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
   playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
   self.videoLayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
   player.play()
}

@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    p.seek(to: .zero)
    }


}
```

Comment: Check this out :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258312/how-to-loop-video-with-avplayerlooper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `notification` listener to trigger the `playerItemDidReachEnd` code.
You do this by involving a `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` in your setup.

Did not test your code, but you want a setup like this example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoLayer: UIView!

var player: AVPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playBackgroundVideo()
}

func playBackgroundVideo()
{
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "City", ofType: "MOV") else{ return }

    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    //# add a Listener 
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self,
                                            selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd),
                                            name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                            object: nil)

    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    self.videoLayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
}

@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) 
{
    player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    player.play()
}
```