# Playback controls in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Attempting to use AVKit's AVPlayer to play a video without playback controls:

```
private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoToPlay", ofType: "mp4")!))
player.showsPlaybackControls = false
```

The above results in an error message that declarations must be separated by ';'.
I've also tried:

```
VideoPlayer(player: player)
    .onAppear {
        player.showsPlaybackControls = false
    }
```

Which results in a different error.

Any advice on hiding playback controls with swiftui?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`VideoPlayer` does not appear to have any methods on it that I can find in the documentation to control whether the playback controls are shown.

`showPlaybackControls` doesn't work because `AVPlayer` doesn't have that property either.

It looks like for now you'll have to do something like wrap an `AVPlayerViewController`:

Note that this is a very limited example and doesn't take into account a lot of scenarios you may need to consider, like what happens when `AVPlayerControllerRepresented` gets reloaded because it's parent changes -- will you need to use `updateUIViewController` to update its properties?  You will also probably need a more stable solution to storing your `AVPlayer` than what I used, which will also get recreated any time the parent view changes. But, all of these are relatively easily solved architectural decisions (look into ObservableObject, StateObject, Equatable, etc)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IMG_0226", ofType: "mp4")!))
    var body: some View {
        AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: player)
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
    }
}

struct AVPlayerControllerRepresented : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, setting `allowsHitTesting` false hides play back controls in iOS 16:

```
private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoToPlay", ofType: "mp4")!))

...

// Disable user interaction on the video player to hide playback controls
VideoPlayer(player: player)
   .allowsHitTesting(false)
```

There may be some corner cases I'm missing where the UI could still appear, but I have yet to encounter that.

Comment: not working for TVOS

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems with playing segments with `VideoPlayer`, so I had to resort to using `AVPlayerLayer` which does not have the controls.

```
class PlayerView: UIView {

    // Override the property to make AVPlayerLayer the view's backing layer.
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass { AVPlayerLayer.self }
    
    // The associated player object.
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get { playerLayer.player }
        set { playerLayer.player = newValue }
    }
    
    private var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer { layer as! AVPlayerLayer }
}

struct CustomVideoPlayer: UIViewRepresentable {
    let player: AVQueuePlayer

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PlayerView {
        let view = PlayerView()
        view.player = player
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PlayerView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Usage:

```
CustomVideoPlayer(player: player)
                .onAppear() {
                    player.play()
                }
                .onDisappear() {
                    player.pause()
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
```

Comment: `AVPlayerLayer` gives the most options, very useful for implementing custom playback controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct GifyVideoView : View {
    let videoName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoName, withExtension: "mp4") {
            GifyVideoViewWrapped(url: url)
        } else {
            Text("No video for some reason")
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct GifyVideoViewWrapped: View {
    let player : AVPlayer
    
    var pub = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
    
    init(url: URL) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: player)
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .onReceive(pub) { (output) in
                player.play()
            }
    }
}

fileprivate struct AVPlayerControllerRepresented : NSViewRepresentable {
    var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> AVPlayerView {
        let view = AVPlayerView()
        view.controlsStyle = .none
        view.player = player
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: AVPlayerView, context: Context) { }
}
```

usage:

```
GifyVideoView(VideoName: "someMp4VideoName")
    .frame(width: 314, height: 196 * 2)
    .clipShape( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous) )
```

video will be played looped ant without controls.

Video will be taken from project resources

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Another great option is to use a video layer instead of an AVPlayerViewController. This is especially useful if the video needs to repeat, for example, since that seems to be the only way to support that use-case.

Since you're just displaying a video layer, there are no controls by default.

[How to loop video with AVPlayerLooper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258312/how-to-loop-video-with-avplayerlooper)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide system-provided playback controls and still support tap gesture, you can use the following approach.

```
ZStack {
    VideoPlayer(player: model.player)
        .disabled(true)

    Button {
        isPlaying.toggle()
    } label: {
        Color.clear
    }
}
```