# How can I hide the buttons on the Video Player with SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: swiftui, avplayer, video-player, avkit

```
VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "*****", ofType: "mp4")!)))
```

How can I hide the buttons on the VideoPlayer. I want the video to be repeated constantly.
You can access the VideoPlayer object by importing the AVKit library.

```
import AVKit
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928091/560942

Comment: I tried the AVKit and AVFoundation import but could not access AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: Is this building for macOS or iOS?

Comment: I am developing applications for macOS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To hide video controls on macOS (wrapping `AVPlayerView`):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IMG_0226", ofType: "mp4")!))
    var body: some View {
        AVPlayerControllerRepresented(player: player)
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
}

struct AVPlayerControllerRepresented : NSViewRepresentable {
    var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> AVPlayerView {
        let view = AVPlayerView()
        view.controlsStyle = .none
        view.player = player
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: AVPlayerView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

To loop `AVPlayer`:
[How do you loop AVPlayer in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808266/how-do-you-loop-avplayer-in-swift)